# readValue() no working with TypeReference

Tags: json, jackson

I am writing following code to convert my JSON sting to list of my object.

```
List<MyObject> myResponse = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
myResponse = new ObjectMapper().readValue(responseString, new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>(){});
```

But eclipse is complaining with following error:

```
The method readValue(String, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (String, new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>(){})
```

What can be possible error?

Comment: What is the myResponse type?

Comment: It is List<MyObject>. Question updated for this.

Comment: Looks like an Eclipse compiler bug. Try to compile the same code with javac (Netbeans, IntelliJ)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Issue was with import of TypeReference. I was using

`import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference`

instead of

`import org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference`

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was with import of ObjectMapper. I was using

> import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.ObjectMapper

instead of

> import org.codehaus.jackson.type.ObjectMapper